# How to access name and type of custom lookup like with WhoId and WhatId for events?

Tags: apex, soql, lookup, event

I am trying to display users' custom lookup field information for events. The WhoId and WhatId of events allow you to use Who.Name and Who.Type in the query to get that information.

I am wondering if there is a way to do this with custom lookups? My understanding is that, unlike whoId and whatId, custom made lookups are restricted to one object (like User).

I have a test one that is a lookup for User object called Find_User__c.

I have tried to use Find_User__r.Name and Find_User__c.Name and get errors saying those are both invalid fields.

**Update:
Sorry, I noticed that my query doesn't fail when I have Find_User__c, and Find_User__r.Name in it. However, after I query those and try to access the information and do event.get(refName+'.Name') I get the invalid field error. (refName = Find_User__r).

Comment: Find_User__r.Name should work, but Find_User__r.Type would not.

Comment: Sorry, updated my question as Find_User__r.Name seems to work in the query... but then it won't let me access that field on the event with event.get().

Comment: So, this is actually a Lightning question?

Comment: I don't think so... This is in apex code. I query all the events, then after getting the list of events, go through and extract information in a loop. And one of the things I want to extract is this custom lookup, but when trying the Find_User__r.Name field it says it is invalid field.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: I have tried to use Find_User__r.Name and Find_User__c.Name and get errors saying those are both invalid fields.

There is an issue in finding proper relationship name. `Find_User__r` has not been defined as relationship name which you are trying to access.

Go to Workbench and try to find actual relationship name for that object. Here is an example.

[image: Account relationship name]

**Update**

Try to access Find_User__r.Name as follows, `evt.get('Find_User__r.Name')` will not work :

```
Event evt = [SELECT Id, Subject, Find_User__c, Find_User__r.Name FROM Event WHERE Id = '00U9000001WD8hb'];
System.debug('User Name=' + evt.Find_User__r.Name);
```

Comment: Hmmm... when searching for Event object, then going to my Find_User__c field, the relationship name says it is Find_User__r

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Sorry, just came back to this issue. I have seen that I get the right value if I do evt.Find_User__r.Name, it is just the issue with the evt.get(). However, how then do you access that information dynamically? I don't necessarily know what lookup fields (if any) will be there, thus I was using event.get().